# [Python]; Parser error: Too many columns specified

Tags: python, machine-learning, pandas-datareader

I just want to read a simple .csv file with a header specifying the column types.
The following is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
url="https://www.dropbox.com/s/n6yt908tgetuq63/LasVegasTripAdvisorReviews-Dataset.csv?dl=0"
names=['User country','Nr. reviews','Nr. hotel reviews','Helpful 
votes','Score','Period of stay','Traveler Type','Pool','Gym','Tennis 
court','Spa','Casino','Free internet','Hotel name','Hotel stars','Nr. 
rooms','User continent','Member years','Review month','Review weekday']
data=pd.read_csv(url, names=names, header=0, delimiter=';', 
error_bad_lines=False)
print(data.shape)
```

OUT:-

> ParserError: Too many columns specified: expected 20 and found 2

P.S:The URL is public and can be accessed

Comment: So I did use the URL setting dl=1, and now I get this error: runfile('C:/Python27/Machinelearning.py', wdir='C:/Python27')
(504, 20)

Comment: It is not an error. It just indicates that you are running that file

Comment: Yeah but I'm not getting any output, that's why.

Comment: `(504, 20)` is the value for `data.shape`. No?

Comment: My bad, I was expecting an array. Its supposed to output the dimensions. Thanks a lot though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the URL doesn't directly lead to the `.csv` file. It leads to the entire html page.

You can see that by removing the `names` argument

`pd.read_csv(url, header=0, delimiter=';', error_bad_lines=False)`

This successfully executes, but when inspecting the returned values, you'll see html code and JavaScript scripts.

What you need to do is make sure you provide actual csv as input (try another source for the `.csv` file)

Comment: I can use numpy's .loadtxt function and directly specify the filename, but I want to use Pandas for this. Do you have a pithy way for "how to read a .csv file using pandas.read_csv function?"

Comment: You're on the right path already - just change the `url` variable to a URL that leads directly to the CSV file. `url="https://www.dropbox.com/s/n6yt908tgetuq63/LasVegasTripAdvisorReviews-Dataset.csv?dl=1"`

Answer (score 1):

In dropbox url just replace 0 with 1 as below
https://www.dropbox.com/s/n6yt908tgetuq63/LasVegasTripAdvisorReviews-Dataset.csv?**dl=1**

Which makes the file to be downloaded directly

Comment: I already have the .csv file but don't know how to provide a readable path for it. That's why I dropped it in the dropbox to create a URL hoping it would lead to the csv file but apparently it is linking the entire HTML page as Adelin pointed out.

Comment: In that case u need to give absolute path of your csv file.

Comment: As in just copy and paste the file location on my PC explicitly?

Comment: yes.if it is windows either make the path separator as / or use double slash(\\)